# GCM notifications are not received

Tags: android, android-notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I am implementing GCM at the moment in my app, I am successfully registering device ID, but I do not get any notifications when I send them from server.
Here are parts of my code:
Manifest

```
 <receiver
        android:name=".services.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
            <category android:name="com.test.gcm"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name=".services.GcmIntentService"/>
```

And inside package services the GcmBroadcastReceiver:

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ComponentName component = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                GcmIntentService.class.getName());

        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(component)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
}
```

And finally gcmIntentService

```
public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {

    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;

    public GcmIntentService() {
        super("GcmIntentService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

        if (!extras.isEmpty()) {
            sendNotification("Notification " + extras.toString());
        }

        GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }

    private void sendNotification(String message) {
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setContentTitle("Notification")
                        .setContentText(message)
                        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle())
                        .setAutoCancel(true);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

I have no idea what might be wrong, no idea even how could I debug it. 
Thanks for any help

Comment: The first step is to check the response on your server when you send the message. You need to see 'success' as opposed to 'failure'

Answer (score 0):

when it comes to GCM, it is very particular about services and receivers name. 
the receiver name should be

```
 <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="com.packagename" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

and for services it should be

```
    <service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />
```

Also, the GCMIntentService should be in the same package as that of your launcher class.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the way to try to start the service :

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ComponentName component = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                GcmIntentService.class.getName());

        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(component)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
}
```

You initialize a `ComponentName` with `context.getPackageName()` which is the main package of your app (`com.test.gcm`), but your `GcmIntentService` class is located in a different package (`com.test.gcm.services`).

You can either specify the correct package name :

```
ComponentName component = new ComponentName(
                    GcmIntentService.class.getPackage ().getName (),
                    GcmIntentService.class.getName());
```

Or you can start the service in a different way :

```
Intent gcmIntent = new Intent(context, GcmIntentService.class);
gcmIntent.putExtras(intent.getExtras());
startWakefulService(context, gcmIntent);
```